# Angular.js: HTML/CSS is not updating when controller changes selected item on list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have setup my application based on a seed project and I am using Controller Alias (App.routes.js has controllerAS for each controller I am using so ::NE is a controller alias). I have a factory service and manager service that feeds data to the controller. Most of this seems to be working ok.

I am now trying to create a basic HTML view where I display a list of items on the page and when the user selects an item in the list it becomes highlighted (e.g. the CSS updates).

I have managed to get the data to display on the page but when I select an item in the list the CSS style is not updating. My code is below and a screenshot that shows some info I have written out to the log as I click on different items in the list.

**node.html**

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">List of Nodes</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                 <h4>Nodes</h4>
                  <div class="list-group">
                          <a ng-repeat="node in ::NE.node" class="list-group-item" ng-class="{active: selected==node}" ng-click="NE.choose(node)">
                            {{node.id}}
                        </a>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**NodeController.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.node', ['app.nodeService', 'app.nodeManager'])    
        .controller('NodeController', NodeController);

        NodeController.$inject = ['nodeManager', '$log'];

        function NodeController(nodeManager, $log) {

            var vm = this;

            //*************************************************************************
            //* Populate the nodes initially
            //*************************************************************************
            nodeManager.getNode(0).then(function(node) {
                vm.node = node;
            });

            //*************************************************************************
            //* Actions to take when a node is selected from the list
            //*************************************************************************
             vm.choose = function(node) {
                vm.node.selected = node;
                $log.info('vm.choose called!');
                $log.info('vm.node.selected');
                $log.info(vm.node.selected);
            };

        }
})();
```

**Web and Console Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: use '' in class, ng-class="{'active': ::NE.selected==node}"

In Code: vm.selected=node;

Comment: can you use it like that ? ->  ng-repeat="node in NE.node", without the "::" ? ::variable in html means it's a one-time binding so it won't reflect further changes

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works fine. I am interested to understand what I was doing wrong? Also, when I navigate to another route and come back my selected item is no longer selected - is that expected or can I maintain the selected item?

Comment: looks like you were missing the quotes around active => 'active'